# Intermittent mapping failures due to namespaces not being recognised in MarkLogic Data Hub Central

Tags: marklogic

I am using the Data Hub central to curate a xml file.
In the mapping section when I am trying to map the entities with the data from the source XML file I am getting a namespace not recognized error -

> Prefix has no namespace binding:

Can anyone please suggest on how we can fix this ?

Is there any where we can define the namespaces in prior? I know when we use templates, we can do that. But what about using the same in Data Hub central?

Comment: As with a lot of things, sample data, code and/or more detail and context are helpful in order for people to understand where/how the error is encountered. What does the XML look like? What XPath are you attempting to use? Any relevant info about the mapping you are attempting to perform....

Comment: From the XML file which I am loading in the Marklogic data hub , one of the xpath looks like this when I map with an entity in the Curate section 

Shipment:Shipment/BaseType:DocumentHeader/BaseType:DocRefShipment:Shipment/Shipment:ShipmentRef

But this doesnot get parsed and gives a namespace issue which I have mentioned above. And when I give wildcard like * in place of the prefixes , it works fine  when I give like this - 

``` (asterisk sign) *:Shipment/(asterisk sign)*:DocumentHeader/(asterisk sign) :DocRef ```